# Responsive layout, scaling image in a nested div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, nested

i'm new to coding, but i'm trying hard. There's a thing i still fully don't understand. Div inside a div/image scaling and positioning with bootstrap. I'm trying to make a responsive website and need some help with the layout.

Here's the HTML code i have:

```
 <div class="container">
      <!-- Pagrindinis divas -->
      <div id="left_bar" class="col-md-8">

          <div id="image_div">
            <div ><img src="http://placehold.it/120x100"/></div>
          </div>

          <div id="text_div">    
            <div id="heading_text">
                Heading 1
            </div>
            <div id="text" class="p">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis odio a sem hendrerit consectetur. Quisque feugiat eget urna vel consectetur. Curabitur gravida lacus quis consectetur suscipit. Etiam a nulla quis lacus bibendum convallis. Mauris dignissim commodo felis quis semper.
                </div>
            </div>  
          </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Soninis widgetas -->
      <div id="right_bar" class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    Right bar    
      </div><!-- Soninio widgeto pabaiga -->
    </div>
```

Here's an [image](http://oi59.tinypic.com/24yd9wl.jpg)

As the website scales down i want the image and the orange div to scale down too.

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aivaraspauga/nZALL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

The key to make the image scale is to set the width of it to 100%, as I did under #image_div img. This way it will take on the width of it's parent container.

Then you just have to make sure the parent container is fluid. In my example I made it 80%. This way it will always be 80% of the browser width, or the parent width - depending if it's wrapperd in another div.

When the 80% container scales because the img is set to 100% it will always occupy 100% of the 80% container.

Hope that help clear things up.

### Additional Resources

If you're interested in learning more about responsive this book won't disappoint. Super quick read and it'll answer all of your questions on responsive:

http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

### The Example Code + JSFiddle

Here's an example of what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/f25xM/1/
HTML

```
<div class="cf wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Pagrindinis divas -->
        <div id="left_bar" class="cf col-md-8">
            <div id="image_div">
                <img src="***" />
            </div>
            <div id="text_div">
                <div id="heading_text">Heading 1</div>
                <div id="text" class="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur quis odio a sem hendrerit consectetur. Quisque feugiat eget urna vel consectetur. Curabitur gravida lacus quis consectetur suscipit. Etiam a nulla quis lacus bibendum convallis. Mauris dignissim commodo felis quis semper.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Soninis widgetas -->
    <div id="right_bar" class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">Right bar</div>
    <!-- Soninio widgeto pabaiga -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.wrapper {
    background:red
}
.container {
    background:red;
    width:80%;
}
#left_bar, #right_bar {
    float:left;
}
#left_bar {
    background:green;
}
#right_bar {
    background:purple;
    width:20%;
}
#image_div, #text_div {
    float:left;
}
#image_div {
    background:orange;
    width:20%;
}
#image_div img {
    width:100%;
}
#text_div {
    background:yellow;
    width:80%;
}
/* Clearfix */
 .cf:before, .cf:after {
    content:" ";
    /* 1 */
    display: table;
    /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as solved, just incase anybody else comes along with the same question. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, i added percentage width to containers and it did the trick i wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a div inside of "image_div" but you can just set the width of the image to 100%. and that way when the container div resizes, the image will also resize. Not sure if that makes sense, its hard to help you without some of your css or a fiddle or codepen.

Comment: I added a fiddle link with what i have at the moment in the bottom of the post :) The image seems to be re-sizing only when it's affected not the whole div :)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap3 you can just add `class="img-responsive"` to make it 100% of the parent element.